# CFLOCK is extremely slow

Tags: coldfusion

I'm still working on the "zombie" requests issue and while investigating I noticed that these requests, thanks to the slow request log, slow down at CFLOCK.

All of the actions before that take less than 30ms, once it hits the CFLOCK all of sudden it takes 20 seconds.

Is there a reason for this? This is an ancient code base and was recently updated ColdFusion to 2016. Do something change with CFLOCK?

A slow lock:
[image]

What is being locked?

```
 <cflock scope="SESSION" timeout="300" type="EXCLUSIVE" throwontimeout="Yes">
```

Why? I'm not 100% certain yet, the code was written back in 2006 and now its my responsibility. From what I can tell this is part of the login page and it locks the session scope while it queries the database to establish a session. Furthermore while querying the database they use an exclusive lock

Comment: What are you locking, and why?

Comment: <cflock scope="SESSION" timeout="300" type="EXCLUSIVE" throwontimeout="Yes">

Why? I'm not 100% certain yet, the code was written back in 2006 and now its my responsibility. From what I can tell this is part of the login page and it locks the session scope while it queries the database to establish a session. Furthermore while querying the database they use an exclusive lock.

Comment: In many cases, and not just with programming, if you can't justify something, it might be unjustified.  Those locks might be an example.

Comment: Does the entire session need to be locked? Not just a single part of it?

Comment: *Why?* Honestly, it is impossible to say. You will have to review the app to try and deduce possible reasons. If it is a really old application, they may have mistakenly thought session variables still needed locking. It was required way back in CF4/5, but has not been the case for a long time. Re: *locks the session scope while it queries the database to establish a session.* A "session" (in the CF sense) is established long before that .cfm script executes, so locking is not necessary to create a session. Using cflock on a db transaction is usually a mistake. (cont'd)

Comment: .. (cont'd) Though I have seen a few legacy applications use cflock in lieu of real db transactions or locking - with varying results. Usually w/the application scope though, not session.  (Neither is a good approach IMO, but I have seen it done). Most likely the locking is mistake or misunderstanding of CF, but again only you can determine that by reviewing the code.